# Setting up two smtp accounts to send emails on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, smtp

I need to set up two accounts to send smtp emails through outlook 365.  Any ideas on how to do this through wordpress.  I have found the code for 1 smtp account; however, i need 2 accounts

Here i need to return the first parameter in.....

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email' );
function send_smtp_email( $phpmailer ) {

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();

    // The second argument to this is the default, so if a hook overrides it and
    // returns true we should do something special
    if(apply_filters('woocommerce_email_headers', false)){
        $phpmailer->Host       = SMTP_WC_HOST;
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = SMTP_WC_AUTH;
        $phpmailer->Port       = SMTP_WC_PORT;
        $phpmailer->Username   = SMTP_WC_USER;
        $phpmailer->Password   = SMTP_WC_PASS;
        $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_WC_SECURE;
        $phpmailer->From       = SMTP_WC_FROM;
        $phpmailer->FromName   = SMTP_WC_NAME;
    }else{
        $phpmailer->Host       = SMTP_HOST;
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = SMTP_AUTH;
        $phpmailer->Port       = SMTP_PORT;
        $phpmailer->Username   = SMTP_USER;
        $phpmailer->Password   = SMTP_PASS;
        $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
        $phpmailer->From       = SMTP_FROM;
        $phpmailer->FromName   = SMTP_NAME;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the "two accounts" thing for a bit, is it that you want WordPress to send two emails instead of one every time?

Comment: First thanks for the reply....for example i want one account to be associated with woocommerce and the other account associated with reservation forms.  Just one email for online orders and 1 email for any reservation. Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Normally, the major reason for setting up a custom SMTP setting is because you are trying to control the FROM part of the email. Do both of these emails really need to come FROM different domains? And by "really", I mean "really, really, really"? The FROM will get you through the door, there's a REPLY-TO that you can also set if you are worried about that. Most SMTP servers including Microsoft's, once you authenticated, will allow you to send TO anyone you want.

Comment: Well, honestly i have to set this up at the whim of the people handling the email.  They refuse to add dkim records to the domain, and want to override wordpresses php method of sending email.  They say it is more secure, but i honestly disagree.  As  far as where the emails are coming from, they are from the same domain.  Essentially, if a person orders an item, they want the from address ''order@domain.com''.  If the person fills a form out to reserve a place in the restuarant, they want ''reservations@domain.com''.  I have no problem implementing this with one authenticated acount...

Comment: But the settings in ''from address'' override any other address.  I just have to find a way to set up two smpt accounts on wordpress.

Comment: that all makes sense, I've been in a similar boat before. Hopefully the answer I posted makes sense

Comment: Thanks Chris! i'll have a look at your answer :)!!!!!

Comment: Ok, so basically the below code :  woocommerce orders could be the first argument and everything else could be the defualt.  Do you know the filter to trigger a woocommerce order email? Or do you have any idea how to essemble the code below where the first argument would be a woocommerce order? Thanks for getting me this far by the way :)))!!!!

Comment: There's a filter called [`woocommerce_email_headers`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Emails.html#583) that appears to be called every do, I'd try that, just make sure to return the first parameter

Comment: Hey Chris, i have halfway (or thirdway lol:)) made it.  I've managed to set up the two addresses but the woocommerce i'm having trouble filtering.  You mentioned make sure i return the first parameter, and this is what i think i'm not doing.  Sorry for being elementary, but could you explain this a bit more? I can provide you the code i'm using if that helps:

Comment: I just updated my answer, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to look for a specific action/filter that is triggered per-plugin to modify. For instance, if you were using Gravity Forms you could hook into [`gform_pre_send_email`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_send_email/), [`gform_notification_email`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_notification_email/), or maybe [`gform_pre_notification_activated`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_notification_activated/), and when that fires set a custom flag of your own. Then in your PHPMailer code look for that flag and change your logic.

Here's just some sample code that I didn't test but should get the logic through. I'm using a custom action however you could also use a global variable if you wanted to. The comments should hopefully make sense.

```php
// Fires right before GravityForms sends an email
add_filter(
    'gform_pre_send_email',
    static function ($email) {

        // Call a function that sets up a filter to override our SMTP settings
        add_filter('should-use-gravity-forms-account', 'use_gravity_forms_special_smtp_code');

        // This is a filter hook, so we need to return what we were given
        return $email;
    }
);

// Fires right after GravityForms is done sending emails
add_action(
    'gform_after_email',
    static function () {
        // Remove our override function
        remove_filter('should-use-gravity-forms-account', 'use_gravity_forms_special_smtp_code');
    }
);

// This is called by our hooks to tell our SMTP code to use a special setting for GravityForms
function use_gravity_forms_special_smtp_code()
{
    return true;
}

add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email' );
function send_smtp_email( $phpmailer ) {

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();

    // The second argument to this is the default, so if a hook overrides it and
    // returns true we should do something special
    if(apply_filters('should-use-gravity-forms-account', false)){
        $phpmailer->Host       = SMTP_GRAVITY_HOST;
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = SMTP_GRAVITY_AUTH;
        $phpmailer->Port       = SMTP_GRAVITY_PORT;
        $phpmailer->Username   = SMTP_GRAVITY_USER;
        $phpmailer->Password   = SMTP_GRAVITY_PASS;
        $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_GRAVITY_SECURE;
        $phpmailer->From       = SMTP_GRAVITY_FROM;
        $phpmailer->FromName   = SMTP_GRAVITY_NAME;
    }else{
        $phpmailer->Host       = SMTP_HOST;
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = SMTP_AUTH;
        $phpmailer->Port       = SMTP_PORT;
        $phpmailer->Username   = SMTP_USER;
        $phpmailer->Password   = SMTP_PASS;
        $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
        $phpmailer->From       = SMTP_FROM;
        $phpmailer->FromName   = SMTP_NAME;
    }
}
```

*edit*

Here's a version that *might* work with WooCommerce. I didn't find anything that disables it, however, but I don't think that is a super big deal.

```php
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_email_headers',
    static function ($headers) {

        // Call a function that sets up a filter to override our SMTP settings
        add_filter('should-use-gravity-forms-account', 'use_gravity_forms_special_smtp_code');

        // This is a filter hook, so we need to return what we were given
        return $headers;
    }
);
```

That said, there's a really interesting filter from Woo that might work even better, [`woocommerce_mail_callback`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email.html#609). That filter would allow you to override the actual core `wp_mail` function in a Woo-safe fashion. But you'd have to test that one, I don't have WC installed anywhere unfortunately.